# Allow signing of pdf using iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext, signature, signing

I'm trying to allow signing for a pdf using iText and Java. I'm not interested in actually signing it, just enabling the "Signing" flag as seen in the image below. Also, I don't need the signing to appear visually anywhere in the document.

[image: Signing]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be done with Adobe tools.  There is no way to change the setting without signing it in iText.